# Validate HABTM resource belong to the same organization

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a HABTM relationship between users and assessments and they both belong to an organization, when an admin user tries want to create an assessment, i want to validate that the selected users(multiple users can be selected via a checkbox) belong to the selected organization in the form

User model

```
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable

  has_and_belongs_to_many :assessments, optional: true
  belongs_to :organization, optional: true
end
```

Assessment model

```
class Assessment < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Organization model

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :assessments, through: :participants
end
```

Here is what i tried but doesn't work properly because am not sure to get the user parameter

```
 def validate_users(user)
   organization.users.include?(user) == true
 end
```

Below is the form

```
form do |f|
 f.inputs do
   f.input :title, as: :string
   f.inputs 'Assign Users' do
     f.input :users, as: :check_boxes, collection: User.all
   end

     f.input :organization, collection: Organization.all
 end

 f.actions
end
```

Comment: try something like `organization.users.where(id: user.id).exists?`

Comment: I get this error message `invalid method user, did you mean users` @fanta

Comment: that code should go inside your `validate_users(user)` method. There you have the `user` object.

Comment: still doesn't work, i am trying to ensure that the selected users belong to the selected organization

Comment: it should work, if the Organization you're using in the `validate_user` method, is the one you're validating against to, then it should work because `organization.users` would give you the users that belong to that organization, and the `where` is just searching in that collection. If it doesn't work, then we'd need more details(code) on how your doing  it.

Comment: perhaps you could show the full code you think will work please @fanta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test whether the associated users are within the organization's list of users. You can do this by subtracting the organization's user_ids from the assessment's. If the result is not an empty array, then there are users outside of the organization's.

If there are users outside of the organization, then you need to add to the object's errors array to trigger it as invalid:

```
class Assessment < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :organization

  validate :users_in_organization

  def users_in_organization
    org_user_ids = organization.try(:user_ids) || [] # catches if there is no organization
    errors.add(:users, "not in organization's users") if (user_ids - org_user_ids).present?

  end
end
```

**NOTE:** I assumed you can have a `belongs_to` relationship between Assessment -> Organization since you already have the corresponding `has_many` in Organization. If that's not the case you will need to get the appropriate organization's user IDs in a different way.

See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods for more detail on custom validation methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class Assessment < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  validate :users_are_in_same_org?

  def users_are_in_same_org?
    return true unless users.any?

    organisation.user_ids.include?(user_ids)
  end
end
```

The above assumes you want an assessment with no users to be valid.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, i need to validate that users selected actually exist in the selected organization too

Comment: That's what the above does I think, organisation.user_ids will list you every user_id in the organisation, and then you check if that array includes all the user_ids associated with the assessment

Comment: This won't work as `include?` checks if the specified object is in the array, and the object could be anything. For example: `[1,2,3].include?([1,2])` is false, whereas `[[1,2],3].include?([1,2])` is true

Answer (score 0):

When submitting the form you will receive an organization_id in the params and a user_ids array.

First find the organization and then check if the user_ids from that organization includes the user_ids that you received in the params.

```rb
class Assessment < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  validate :organization_includes_users

  def organization_includes_users
    org = Organization.find(organization_id)
    if user_ids-org.user_ids == []
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

The user_ids-org.user_ids compares the 2 arrays. If the first array has elements that the second array doesn't have then it will return an array with those elements.

Comment: Your answer was pretty close, just the `Organization.find(organization_id)` that returned an error message, Thanks anyways @Hackman